# To show sequence converges and find limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

need to detailed solution, if possible.....
Let  $ 0\lt a\le1 , s_1=\frac a2 $ and for $ n\in\ N$, let $s_{n+1}=\frac 12(s_n^2+a)  $.
Show that the sequence {$s_n$} is convergent,and find its limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show by induction:

1) $s_{n+}$ is bounded by 1: $s_n^2 \leq 1$, $a \leq 1$. So, $s_{n+1} \leq 1$

2) $s_n$ is increasing. $2(s_{n+1}-s_n)=(s_n^2-s_{n-1}^2)$. Show that $s_2 > s_1 =a/2$- which is true as $\frac{a^2}{4} \geq 0$

3) So, limit exists, say limit = L.

4) L satisfies $L= \frac{1}{2}(L^2+a)$

Can you solve the rest?

Comment: how is it bounded? and its certainly not decreasing,because if we take a=1 , then 1st term is 0.5 , 2nd term is 0.6.plz analyze it step by step so that i can understand better.

Comment: @ketan: added more details. The seq. is increasing- that's what I meant to type; decreasing was a typo :)

Comment: since we do not know what function involving 'a' the Nth term of this sequence is, therefore how can it be necessarily said to be bounded.

Comment: use induction. You know $a$ is less than 1.

Comment: ya i just solved it with your hints.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To expand, I'm pretty sure voldemort meant $s_n$ is increasing. You can prove that by induction. Assume $s_n < s_{n+1}$ is true for $\forall n \le k$ then prove $s_{k+1} < s_{k+2} \Leftarrow\Rightarrow \frac 12(s_k^2 + a) < \frac 12 (s_{k+1}^2 +a)$. You should have it from there. It will be helpful to remember $s_n > 0$ when you take square roots (since $s_1 > 0$ and $s_{n+1} > s_n$ per our assumption). I'll leave the base case to you.

Finding the actual limit then is simple algebra.

$\frac 12L^2 - L + \frac a2 = 0$

Apply quadratic formula:

$L = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4 \frac12 \frac a2}}{2\frac12}$

You should have it from there.